# How to know from where element.style is applied into CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<ul></ul>`class in which an `element.style{}` is getting applied from a .js file. Can I know how to know the exact `.js` file from which it is getting applied and the line of code? Below is the ss attached.
[image: Code snippet]]

Comment: no... Or I don't know how and if I knew, it would have saved me years! The best trick I have now for this is to use a keyword search tool like [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) on the possible files to find it. Then by try and fail... narrow the possibilities.

Comment: If your editor has a "Find In Project" function or similar, you could search for `transition-duration` or `width: 800%`. It won't be perfect and you'll probably get lots of false positives, but it may give you some clues. For example, Shift+Ctrl+F is the shortcut for it in Atom Editor.

Comment: Search the code base using keyword like translate3d(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for some file name with **flexslider** or **jquery.flexslider.js**. If you have it then css is coming from their only search with `.slides` or with `translate3d`. If you don't have any then
the only possible way is with cleaver search. 1st search with `".slides"` within your project. If you found any normal class not any library thats the place where it is coming. If you found any file like slider, carousel or owl or any other js file just delete the content of those file and refresh the page if the css is still their look for other file. If nothing happen look with parent class or ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an IDE you can do a search for the styles applied in question in the javascript files, the IDE will highlight all the occurrences of the keywords that you use to search for. If the JavaScript file has been minified it can make it impossible because you won't have any idea what is what without a lot of analysis work. If you have the original source code just do a search it will allow you to do analysis really quick.

Answer (score -1):

In Microsoft Edge if you click inspect element the CSS of element will appear on the right side of the screen. You can see which CSS style are being applied and use the checkmark interface to apply or remove the style. This will tell exactly where the CSS is coming from. If you want to know where the JavaScript is coming from I will use the search feature in my text editor to find the specific functions, or remove script tag temporary until I locate it.

Comment: OP sais the CSS rule seems to be applied by a JS script. The Edge inspector is no-use in that case.

Comment: Oh, he is looking for the JavaScript.